# How to implement speech recognition training in c# speech application

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I want to add speech recognition training in my speech application i tried and searched alot but didn't come up with any solution.

```
    string ex = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\windows\\sysnative", "Speech\\SpeechUX\\SpeechUX.dll, RunWizard User Training");
    string mode = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\windows\\sysnative", "rundll32.exe");
    Process.Start(mode, ex);
```

but it gives run time error saying,

```
    There was a problem starting
    C:\Windows\sysnative\Speech\SpeechUX\SpeechUX.dll
    The specified module could not be found.
```

I have added sysnative as I searched and i got this as for x64 bit windows the system files are stored in sysnative.

Comment: Nothing about this looks right. I've never worked with the speech recognition libraries in Windows 7, but a quick Google search came up with this, which looks a lot more inline with what I'd expect. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @senfo I created my speech application using this speech recognition but stuck at the training part.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little bit more about what you'd like to do? I suspect you've come across some rather lousy training.

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition is part of the Microsoft core know-how. I will not be available to you for sure. They might let you do some sort of speaker adaptation, but this is not going to improve much of your accuracy except for a single speaker. You should read about speaker adaptation, find out if Microsoft offers such a feature, and finally decide if this really fits your application.